# Moving a file to the iCloud with [moveItemAtURL:toURL:error:]: only a copy is made

Tags: objective-c, copy, icloud

I use this code in a function which is used to manage a file on the iCloud. When I call it to move the file from the cloud to the local computer, there is roughly 1 in 30 chance that the file is only copied, not moved. However, the call to `moveItemAtURL` returns YES, with no error. Except for this call, no operation is done in the cloud (I don't read or write other files at the same time).

I tried the `setUbiquitous:itemAtURL:destinationURL:error:` function too, but the result is the same.

Is it possible that the file is locked, so it can only be copied and not moved? Or is it a synchronization issue?

Thanks

```c
dispatch_async(operationQueue, ^(void) {
    __block NSError *err1 = nil;
    __block NSError *err2 = nil;
    NSFileManager * fm = [ NSFileManager defaultManager];
    __block bool success = true;

    NSFileCoordinator *fc = [[[ NSFileCoordinator alloc ] initWithFilePresenter: nil ] autorelease ];
    [ fc coordinateWritingItemAtURL : i_srcDocumentURL options:NSFileCoordinatorWritingForReplacing
                    writingItemAtURL: i_dstDocumentURL options:NSFileCoordinatorWritingForReplacing
                              error : &err1  byAccessor: 
    ^(NSURL *newURL1, NSURL *newURL2) {
        [ fm removeItemAtURL: newURL2 error:nil];//Remove destination file in case there is one
        if(  [ fm moveItemAtURL:newURL1 toURL:newURL2 error:&err2 ] == FALSE )
        {
            success = false;
        }
    } ];

    if( err1 )
    {
        success = false;
        [self logError:err1];
    }
    if( err2 )
    {
        success = false;
        [self logError:err2];
    }
    dispatch_async( mainQueue, ^(void) {
        if (success) {
            i_answerObj->MoveFileOk([i_fileName UTF8String]);
        }
        else 
        {
            i_answerObj->MoveFileError([i_fileName UTF8String]);
        }
        [self destroyMyself];
    });
});
```

Comment: This code doesnt work I dont have time to debug it for you see answer

Comment: Maybe you should use NSFileCoordinatorWritingForMoving

Answer (score 0):

setUbiquitous:false removes the file from iCloud end of story and puts a copy at the target location.

removing a file from the ubiquity container removes the file from iCloud, end of story no move done.

move file moves a file.

Having built 5 apps on top of iCloud I can tell you need to look at your code.

Remove a file from iCloud and put on local machines: setUbi...FALSE target.

Delete a file from iCLoud

NSFileManager removeFile - from the ubiquity container.

Your working way too hard.

Comment: I already tried 'setUbiquitous:false'; a copy is made at the target location and sometimes the file is not removed from the cloud. Can I call a function to force an iCloud sync?

Comment: from the cloud or from the local ubiquity container?  Big difference

Comment: From the local container. Since the local container is supposed to be a mirror of what's in the cloud, I don't really see the difference here...